# The cone of a topological space is contractible and simply connected

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, proof-verification

I would like help in verifying my proof and making it rigorous.

**Question:**

Let $X$ be a topological space. The cone on $X$, denoted $CX$, is the quotient space $(X × [0, 1])/(X × \{0\})$.  Prove that $CX$ is contractible and simply connected?

(note: $X/A$ is the quotient space $X/\mathord{∼}$ for an equivalence relation $∼$ on $X$ such that the equivalence classes are $A$ itself, and the singletons $\{x\}$ such that $x \notin A$.)

**My Answer:**

A [previous answer by kobe](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1065738) shows that $CX$ is contractible:

> Consider the map $H: X \times [0,1] \times [0,1] → X \times [0,1]$ defined by $H((x,t),s) = (x(1-s)t)$. Then $H$ is continuous and $H((x,0,s) = (x,0)$ for all $x∈X$ and $s∈[0,1]$.  $H$ induces a continuous map $\hat{H}$: $CX \times [0,1] → CX$ such that $\hat{H}([(x,t)],s) = [(x,(1-s)t)]$.  Now $\hat{H}[(x,t)],0) = [(x,t)]$ and $\hat{H}[(x,t)],1) = [(x,0)] = X \times \{0\}$. So $\hat{H}$ is a homotopy in $CX$ from the identity on $CX$ to the point $X \times \{0\}$.  Consequently, $CX$ is contractible.

$CX$ is simply connected as a result of being contractible.  To show this, we show that all contractible spaces are simply connected.  Let $X$ by contractible.  We will show that any loop in $X$ is homotopic, relative to $\{ 0,1 \}$, to the constant loop.  Observe that the homotopy $F$ from the identity on $X$ to the constant map at $x∈X$ gives us a homotopy $G(s,t) = F(α(s),t)$ from any loop $α$ based at $x$ to the constant loop at $x$.  We must show that the homotopy is relative to $\{0,1\}$. We use the fact that the square $[0,1] \times[0,1]$ is convex, so there is a straight line homotopy $H$ between any two paths from $a$ to $b$ in $[0,1] \times [0,1]$, and so any two such paths are homotopic relative to $\{0,1\}$.  Using this, we see that the path along the left edge of the square is homotopic, relative to $\{0,1\}$, to the path along the bottom edge, up the right edge and back along the top edge of the square.  Composing the homotopies $H$ and $G$ gives us the homotopy relative to $\{0,1\}$.  We have shown that any loop in $X$ is homotopic, relative to $\{0,1\}$, to the constant loop and so it is path connected and the fundamental group $π_1(X,b)$ for a loop based at $b$ has only one element and $π_1(X,b) = \{e\}$ where $e$ is a constant.  $X$ is path-connected and has a trivial fundamental group.  Then it is simply connected.  Contractible spaces are simply connected.  Then $CX$ is simply connected.

Comment: I think you mean $\hat{H}([(x,t)],s)=[(x,(1-s)t)]$. You have $x$ instead of the first $s$, which makes no $s$ on the left hand side.

Comment: You probably mean "*... and singletons $\{x\}$ such that $x\not\in A$*" in the second **My question**-paragraph.

Comment: It appears that the proof in the question body was plagiarized from [the answer to this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1065706/how-to-prove-the-cone-is-contractible)...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proving that the join of a path-connected space with an arbitrary space is simply-connected](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187562/proving-that-the-join-of-a-path-connected-space-with-an-arbitrary-space-is-simpl)

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to deal with the first statement, that $CX$ is contractible.

> Consider the map $H: X \times{[0,1]} \times{[0,1]}$ $→$ $X
>  \times{[0,1]}$ defined by $H((x,t),s) = (x(1-s)t)$. Then $H$ is
>    continuous and $H((x,0,s) = (x,0)$ for all $x∈X$ and $s∈[0,1]$.

Here you show that, whenever two points get identified, namely when they are of the form $(x,0,s)$ and $(x',0,s)$ for $x,x'\in X,s\in I$, then they have the same image $[(x,0)]$.

> $H$ induces a continuous map $\hat{H}$: $CX \times [0,1] → CX$ such that
>    $\hat{H}([(x,t)],s) = [(x,(1-s)t)]$.  Now $\hat{H}[(x,t)],0) =
>  [(x,t)]$ and $\hat{H}[(x,t)],1) = [(x,0)] = X \times${$0$}. So
>    $\hat{H}$ is a homotopy in $CX$ from the identity on $CX$ to the point
>    $X \times${$0$}. Consequently, $CX$ is contractible.

All your computations are correct. The function $\hat H$ *starts* with the identity and *ends* with a retraction $r:CX\to \{X\times\{0\}\}$ (Note that this is also *relative $X\times\{0\}$*, it is independent of the time $s$ on that subspace, so you actually have a *deformation retraction* $r$). The only problem here is that $\hat H$ is continuous only when $q\times\text{id}_I:X\times I\times I\to CX\times I$ is a quotient map. But in general, a product map $q\times\text{id}_Y:X\times Y\to Z\times Y$, where $q$ is a quotient map, is not necessarily a quotient map. Luckily, in your case it is, and this is because $I$ is **locally compact** and $q\times\text{id}_Y$ is a quotient map for each locally compact $Y$. For a proof see theorem 4.3.2 in the book [Topology and Groupoids](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/topgpds.html).